# Передача из класса в класс

Tags: java

Есть 2 класса `fromspace` и `panelmenu`

`fromspace` - это окно

`panelmenu` - это панель

К `fromspace` уже прикреплена `panelmenu`. При нажатии на кнопку, которая находится на панели, создаётся ещё одна, но я не могу её прикрепить к окну, так как надо её туда передать.

Как можно передать панель в `formspace`?

Comment: Код в студию. И какая визуальная библиотека используется?

Comment: Код я в данный момент дать не могу так как просто данный вариант я рассматривал ещё давно , и в итоге приходиться опять пробовать с панелями так как я для Mac не могу найти API для работы с окнами , для windows это WinAPI а на счёт библиотеки то Swing

Comment: "При нажатии на кнопку, которая находиться на панели, создаётся ещё одна,..."  еще одна кнопка? или панель?  @TwerTrue, пожалуйста уточните.